Cyclic structure of fructose
In D-(+)-glucose -OH at C-5 attacks the aldehydic group forming it's cyclic structure.Some people explain reason behind the attack of -OH at C-5 is the formation of 6 membered pyranose ring,which is more stable than higher or lower membered rings.

Why not same occur in case of D-(-)-fructose.Why not -OH at C-6 attacks the ketonic group forming a 6-membered stable pyranose ring.Why it exist and mainly studied as it's 5 membered furanose structure.

